# URL Redirection untrusted Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Can anybody tell me how can validate this URL in this line ?

```
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

As this is giving me a security error "URL Redirection untrusted Site" from the Security Scanning tool

Comment: you want to redirect somewhere in your website right..means returnurl will be local???

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to test that the URL is a local URL before performing the redirection as a malformed url could redirect your users to another site (like a phishing site).  As your code currently stands, this URL:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/account/login?returnUrl=www.myfakesite.com
```

will redirect you to `www.myfakesite.com` once you login

By adding this conditional check below, you can ensure you never redirect outside of your current application

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)){
    //check for empty return url and that it is a local url 
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else{
     //wherever you want people to default going to if they 
     //log in without a return url or one that is not a local url.
     return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");
}
```

**EDIT**

The Url helper assembly is located in System.Web.Mvc.  However, in a controller, the UrlHelper is already setup and ready to go - meaning the controller instantiates the UrlHelper "automatically".  In order to use this outside of a controller, you need access to the current `RequestContext` in order to setup the UrlHelper.

```
   var helper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
   return helper.IsLocalUrl("testUrl");
```

**Note** - I have no idea how the security scanning software is determining that this could be a "URL redirection untrusted site" - but it is probably just sending a bad url and seeing if the application is redirecting to it.  This should correct that, but without more information on how the security scan works, I cannot guarantee.

Comment: I cannot add Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) to my code.The namesapce required for this is "System.web.mvc "right ??

Comment: @AnkitBansal - The UrlHelper is in System.Web.Mvc, however, outside of a controller, you need to instantiate the UrlHelper.  See the above edits on how to do that.

Comment: Adding the following line in my controller gives the following error 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  System.web.mvc is already added as a reference.

Comment: @AnkitBansal - The HttpContext is in System.Web (not System.Web.Mvc).  Please ensure you have that reference as well!

Comment: That Really solved my problem... Thnaks a lot...Any idea about the cross site scripting error in this line                            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData.Image)